# How do I apply Ampere's law for a solenoid with a core?

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

I have a solenoid with a ferromagnetic core (like a transformer). Now we know that the magnetic field *H*, is fully restricted inside the ferromagnetic core. My problem is with the application of Ampere's law. The configuration is as below:
[image]

The black box is the ferromagnetic core. Let the red lines be the (closed) paths over which I compute the integral:
\$\oint H \cdot dl=Ni \$

Now, if I select the paths: \$a\to b\to f\to e\to a\$, \$a\to c\to g\to e\to a\$ and finally \$a\to d\to h\to e\to a\$, I get the conflicting equations: \$HA=Ni\$, \$HB=Ni\$ and \$HC=Ni\$ respectively, where:

\$ab+fe+ea=A\$

\$ac+ge+ea=B\$

\$ad+dh+he+ea=C\$

I know I am making a stupid mistake somewhere. Please help...

Comment: H is different on the segment `bf` compared to say, `dh`. Difference may be due to differences in permeability of air and core materials.

Comment: "*Now we know that the magnetic field H, is fully restricted inside the ferromagnetic core.*". I don't think this is true. If we apply Biot-Savart law at mid point of `bf` to find \$B\$ and subsequently \$H = B/\mu\$, will it be exactly zero ?

Comment: KSeeker, yes they all sum to \$N\,i\$ because that's the total current that penetrates the soap bubbles stretched for any of your closed loops. So you know they must all be equal, regardless. But what makes you think that \$\vec{H}\$ is either a constant or else 0 regardless of \$\text{d}\vec{l}\$? Imagine moving around a small rectangle that is  \$\text{d}\vec{l}\$ long and some \$w\$ wide. For some of the path, the part well within the coil region, the value of \$\vec{H}\$ will be constant. But the moment the \$\text{d}\vec{l}\$ moves beyond that, it's no longer constant.

Comment: _""...H, is fully restricted inside the ferromagnetic core.". I don't think this is true."_
You are absolutely correct. But for practical applications, it is negligible.
References for all concerns of AJN and jonk can be found at:
(https://www.ieee.li/pdf/introduction_to_power_electronics/chapter_12.pdf)
page 12 and (http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node106.html) and also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core)
But that is not the problem. The problem is along each of these paths, _H_ is different and so is the integral but the RHS of the equation is the same.

Comment: My point is, (is it true that) the value of _H_ is much higher for paths like \$abfea\$ compared to paths like \$adhea\$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent contradiction arises because you're confusing \$ H\$ with \$ B\$. Remember that \$ H\$ is insensitive to whether or not a magnetic material is present (analogously to how \$ D\$ is insensitive to whether a dielectric is present for electric fields). So the \$ H\$ field between \$ dh\$ is not stronger than the \$ H\$ field between \$ bf\$ (which is not completely zero, and is only neglected because the magnetic flux in the core is much stronger, and the flux is usually what we care about in practical scenarios because it features in Faraday's law). The \$ B\$ field is of course much stronger between \$ dh\$ but as I said, Ampere's law concerns \$ H\$, not \$ B\$. If you want to apply Ampere's law with \$ B\$ rather than \$ H\$, then you need to take into account the permeabilities of the core and the air as you do your line integrals and this difference will account for the apparent contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes the problem occurred to me because in many places, B ah H are used interchangeably.